# Getting total number of objects during simulation OMNET++/VEINS

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins

I am running VEINS simulation for VANETs. Is there a way to access the total number of cars being simulated during a specific time in OMNET++?(I am trying to count the number of packets being exchanged between cars, and since I am broadcasting it, I thought multiplying the packet sent to the number of vehicles being simulated would provide a good indicator of how many received packets count should be).

Answer (score 5):

The return value of [TraCIScenarioManager::getManagedHosts](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.3/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h#L100) contains all active vehicles. You should get the same result as if you manually iterate over (and then filter) all submodules of your network using [cModule::SubmoduleIterator](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classcModule_1_1SubmoduleIterator.html).